# building java project (gradle build) with git submodule

Tags: git, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project that has a `box-java-sdk as git submodule`

I my source root I did:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/chneukirchen/box-java-sdk.git box-java-sdk
```

Now I need to build *MY* project which in turns needs a `box-java-sdk.jar`

At present, I am building box.jar separately and putting inside libs directory in "My" project and build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
        compile files('thirdparty/lib/BoxJavaLibraryV2-1.0.jar')
}
```

I dont want to do this separate building. I just want to do one build of my project which will internally build box submodule and use it as dependency.

How can I automagically build and use-as-dependency Box.jar ONLY using my build.gradle?

I was told that this can be done using git submodule. But I dont know how to do it??

Comment: There is no way to do this automagically. You'll have to turn your build into a multi-project build (see the corresponding chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)), and change the dependency to a *project dependency* (explained in the same chapter).